# NumberFormatException thrown when parsing String to Int

Tags: java, android

Am trying to parse a string to an int value after reading bytes from a stream and appending it to stringbuilder. But when I try to parse the string to an Int value the NumberFormatException is thrown.
Surrounding the statement with a "try and catch" doesn't help either as it parses " " which am guessing is null.

Below is my code explaining my issue in detail:

```
String s = ClientStream.getInputStream(socks.getInputStream());

myDataSplitter splitter = myDataSplitter.getSplitStream(s);

/*
* Parse the page's length in bytes to an Int value.
* (Type)--Header
*/
int contIndx = Integer.parseInt(splitter.getContentLength("Content-Length:"));
```

The `ClientStream.getInputStream()` method code:

```
public static String getInputStream(InputStream inputstream){

    StringBuffer stringbuilder = new StringBuffer();

    while(true) {

        try {
            rdL = inputstream.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("InjectClientStream","Error reading byte from stream", e);
        }
        if(rdL == -1){
            break;
        }
        stringbuilder.append((char) rdL);

        if (stringbuilder.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") != -1) {
            return stringbuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    return stringbuilder.toString();
}
```

The `myDataSplitter.getSplitStream()` method code:

```
public static myDataSplitter getSplitStream(String str1) {

    int i = 0;
    myDataSplitter splitter = new myDataSplitter(str1);

    String[] as = splitter.allInpRequest.split("\r\n",2);

    if(as.length > 1) {

    String[] as1 = as[1].replace("\r\n\r\n", "").split("\r\n");

    if(i <= as1.length) {
        i++;
    String[] as2 = as1[i].split(":");
    try {
        splitter.map.put(as2[0], as2[1]);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
    return splitter;
}
```

Then the method where the **ERROR MESSAGE** is raised.Code ::

```
public String getContentLength(String paramString) {
    //Returns the value of the mapped in string value
    //"Content-Length"
    String s = ((String)this.map.get(paramString));
    if(s != null) {
        return s;
    }
    return ""; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong to start with is reading bytes and believing that they are characters; use a `Reader` if you want to read characters, and don't forget to specify the encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to try:

```
String s = this.map.get(paramString).toString();
```

instead of

```
String s = ((String)this.map.get(paramString))
```